# How to navigate using DPad in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

The Android device I am using does not have any touchscreen. All it has is a touch pad that can generate KEYCODE_DPAD_UP, KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN, etc. It appears, by default, a Xamarin-based app ignores these key codes. I am wondering if there is some way to map these key codes into navigating among the displayed controls. Regards.

Comment: Some D-pads report  AXIS_HAT_XX events instead of KEYCODE_DPAD_XX keypresses. If it is reporting KEYCODE_DPAD_XX keypresses then standard widget navigation will occur whether it is a Java-based app or an Xamarin one as Xamarin is not blocking or changing any keyboard widget navigation

Comment: I am catching OnKeyUp to see what I get. I am getting DpadXXX codes. The problem is there is no way to know what control has been selected and if the selection is changing. I also notice that DpadCenter seems to be work as if clicked on the selected control.

Comment: `no way to know what control has been selected`: The change should be subtle but you should be able to see it (try a different theme for your app). `DpadCenter seems to be work as if clicked on the selected control`: Yes, it will act as an `enter`, so if you highlight a spinner and `DpadCenter` "click" it, the spinner should open and then you can scroll up/down w/ dead and then DpadCenter to select.a new value.